# Microsoft Word 2010 mail merge - statement overdue calculations

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

My company hosts various events for clients (conference meetings, receptions, holiday parties, etc.). After an event is completed, we send out invoices. Monthly we also send out statements for all outstanding invoices.  Our statement form (and invoice form) are auto-filled using a Microsoft Word 2010 mail merge.

Depending on the client, they might have multiple invoices outstanding.  On our statement, we are able to pull in the previously sent out «Invoice_Number», «Event_Date», «Event», and «Invoice_Amount».  Each event is separated with a «Next Record» field.

We want to be able to calculate the total amount of outstanding invoices that are 30 days, 60 days, 90 days, and 120 days overdue and display these at the bottom of the statement.

My question: Is this possible? Can I somehow calculate, based on the «Event_Date» field, which items on the statement are older than 30, 60, 90, and 120 days and calculate total of those items from the «Invoice_Amount» fields and place them under the appropriate overdue label? If so, how?

[image: Statement Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: did you try conditional formatting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the calculations are done before the merge to be the most accurate. Performing calculations with the merge will be rather complicated and prone to error if the `Field Codes` are incompatible.

Within your data source, create the totals for 30, 60, 90 & 120 days per customer. You can then place the field in each of the areas at the bottom for the `<<customer_Id>>` so current total overdue will be populated when the merge is completed.